# Проверка select на выбраное значение js

Tags: javascript, валидация

Задача чтобы при `blur`, если выбрано значение в селекте, он подсвечивался **зелёным**, если стоит ***не указано*** подсвечивался **красным**. У меня сейчас получается **зелёным** при любом выборе.

И второй вопрос если много селектов в одной форме и во всех нужно проверить, как правильно их перебрать циклом?

```js
function checkSelect() {
  const sel = document.getElementById('loan-purpose');
  const selNum = sel.selectedIndex;

  sel.addEventListener('blur', function() {
    if (selNum === 0) {
      sel.className = ('invalid')
    } else {
      sel.className = ('valid')
    }
  });
}

checkSelect();
```

```css
.valid {
  border: 2px solid red;
}

.invalid {
  border: 2px solid green;
}
```

```html
<select name="name" id="loan-purpose" class="form__loan-purpose-input">
  <option value="Не указано">Не указано</option>
  <option value="Ремонт">Ремонт</option>
  <option value="Учеба">Учеба</option>
  <option value="Покупка автомобиля">Покупка автомобиля</option>
  <option value="Лечение">Лечение</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ваша ошибка в том, что Вы получаете selectedIndex до того, как выполняется blur, поэтому значение всегда равно 0. Нужно перенести получение selectedIndex внутрь функции. А если селектов несколько, можно пройтись по ним с помощью, например, forEach:

```js
const allSel = document.querySelectorAll('.form__loan-purpose-input');
allSel.forEach((sel) => {
  sel.addEventListener('blur', function (){
    let selNum = sel.selectedIndex;
    if(selNum === 0){
        sel.className = ('invalid')
    }
    else{
        sel.className = ('valid')
    }
  });
})
```

```css
.invalid  {
  border: 2px solid red;
}

.valid  {
  border: 2px solid green;
}
```

```html
<select name="name" id="loan-purpose1" class="form__loan-purpose-input">
  <option value="Не указано" >Не указано</option>
  <option value="Ремонт">Ремонт</option>
  <option value="Учеба">Учеба</option>
  <option value="Покупка автомобиля">Покупка автомобиля</option>
  <option value="Лечение">Лечение</option>
</select>

<select name="name" id="loan-purpose2" class="form__loan-purpose-input">
  <option value="Не указано" >Не указано</option>
  <option value="Ремонт">Ремонт</option>
  <option value="Учеба">Учеба</option>
  <option value="Покупка автомобиля">Покупка автомобиля</option>
  <option value="Лечение">Лечение</option>
</select>

<select name="name" id="loan-purpose3" class="form__loan-purpose-input">
  <option value="Не указано" >Не указано</option>
  <option value="Ремонт">Ремонт</option>
  <option value="Учеба">Учеба</option>
  <option value="Покупка автомобиля">Покупка автомобиля</option>
  <option value="Лечение">Лечение</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Ещё смотрите почему то наоборот работает. Указано что при значение ноль вешать класс .invalid иначе .valid. Получается .что если выбрано "не указано" подсвечивается зелёным, при других выборах красным. Это в моём варианте, в вашем всё правильно. Не могу понять почему так просто.

Comment: @MaxAkinshin, в моём примере если выбрано "не указано", подсвечивается красным. Я в css специально поменял цвета. Всё-таки по логике invalid должен быть красным, а valid - зелёным (у Вас изначально почему-то наоборот)

Comment: Да точно, моя ошибка что цвета в классах перепутал и думаю почему наоборот работает) Благодарю!